# How to use libg3d to load wavefront models to OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, wavefront, 3d-model

I'm working in my thesis project. I need some help trying to load wavefront (.obj) models to OpenGL. I have been searching, and I found the [Libg3D](http://automagically.de/g3dviewer/) that let's you load a wide variety of 3d model formats.

I'm having problems to understand how to load a model, and if I can libg3d to load a model to my opengl application.

Comment: I've only had a quick look through their documentation, but [`g3d_model_load()​​​`](http://automagically.de/libg3d/libg3d-model.html) might be what you want.